# Angular CLI no such file or directory for Jquery or bootstrap

Tags: angular

I have an angular project that I want to include bootstrap which requires jquery as a dependency.

First I installed bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap --save-dev
```

Then Jquery

```
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

Then I updated my angular.json file

```
"styles": [
   {
     "input": "src/custom-Theme.scss"
   },
   "./node_modues/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
   "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "./node_modues/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

And I have confirmed with windows explorer that both of these files exist and that the path is correct.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

But when I try to compile, I get the following error message:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive -\Documents\Repos\xxx\xxx\node_modues\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css'
>   in 'C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Documents\Repos\xxx\xxx'

I've removed my project name and computer name and replaced it with 'xxx' but that's the original error message. I have no clue what I did wrong. I installed the package using npm. I confirmed that the packages were in the node_modules folder, and then I referenced them in my angular.json file. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

EDIT

So I had a silly spelling mistake. Feels bad. But I fixed that and I'm still getting an error message.

open 'C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive \Documents\Repos\xxx\xxx\node_modues\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

Why is it putting OneDrive there? I didn't specify that. The file path above is not correct and doesn't exist. Could one drive be screwing this up?

EDIT 2

I disabled one drive and then restarted my IDE. Works fine now. Seems that one drive was the culprit. Maybe something to do with how it automatically backs up and syncs files?

Comment: If you copy the full path from your error message, and paste it into Windows Explorer, does it open the file?

Comment: There's a spelling error in your path. Should be **`node_modules`**, not **`node_modues`**

Answer (score 4):

First of all check your package.json file if they are in the dependencies like:

```
"dependencies": {
    .....
    .....
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  },
```

if u are using angular 6 you can ommit the ./ in the angular.json like that:

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/custom-Theme.scss"
  },
  "node_modues/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modues/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

also ommit the -dev like:

```
npm install jquery --save

npm install bootstrap --save
```

since bootstrap is a dependency for your app to run.

a dev-dep would be e.g. angular-cli, codelyzer, karma etc..

give it a shot and let me know if it helped ;)

Comment: This didn't solve my question but they are good suggestions. I followed these after I fixed the issue.

Comment: just saw the typo ;)

Comment: The typo was part of the problem. One Drive appears to be the main culprit. Even after all paths were corrected, it STILL had the issue. See my edit above to see how I fixed it.

Comment: I plan on it as soon as I understand exactly what happened. I assume it was oneDrive but I don't want to give bad advice.

Comment: k, that's a good idea - looking forward to find out what caused that issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Silly spelling mistake it is. `node_modues` should be `node_modules`. It is ideal to copy/paste file paths rather than typing them.

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/custom-Theme.scss"
  },
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

Comment: This was part of the problem but didn't completely solve it. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer - Disable OneDrive

Longer Answer - I don't exactly know what happened. I realized that the file paths that the CLI was spitting out had 'oneDrive' in the path and I know that that path wasn't something I created. Assuming it had to do with Microsoft's OneDrive, I disabled it by right-clicking on the icon in the system tray. I then restarted my IDE and after that it all worked fine. I can't say definitively that OneDrive was the issue or that anyone using it will face the same issues I did. But it's what worked for me so hopefully, this answer helps someone else.